# Get data from a running exe on my pc

Tags: arduino-pro-micro, atmega32u4

I have made a button with an LED using an arduino micro. It's connected to my pc and when I hit the button, the LED activates and a recording on Reaper (digital audio workstation) is started. When I hit the button again, the LED turns off and the recording stops and is saved.

I want the LED to flash at the BPM rate of the project in Reaper. So it needs to read the amount of Beats per minute the project is set to.

Is there any way the arduino can read this value?
Without the flashing LED, the program works fine. Here's the code:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

boolean toggle = false;
int inPin = 2;
int outPin = 3;

int state = HIGH;
int ledOn;
int reading;
int previous = LOW;

long time = 0;
long debounce = 200;

void setup() {
  // make pin 2 an input and turn on the
  // pullup resistor so it goes high unless
  // connected to ground:
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  reading = digitalRead(inPin);
  ledOn = digitalRead(outPin);

  // if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
  // to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
  // the time
  if ((reading == LOW) and (ledOn == LOW)) {
    state = HIGH;
    Keyboard.press((char) 128);
    Keyboard.press('r');
    delay(50);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(300);
  }

  if ((reading == LOW) and (ledOn == HIGH)) {
    state = LOW;
    Keyboard.press((char) 32);
    delay(10);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(100);
    Keyboard.press((char) 177);
    delay(10);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
    delay(300);

    time = millis();
  }

  digitalWrite(outPin, state);

  previous = reading;
}
```

Comment: Never used this program, but apparently it has an API: http://www.reaper.fm/sdk/reascript/reascripthelp.html. If the program does not "publish" the BPM anywhere else where you could read with another software and send to the Arduino via Serial, you may need to write something to talk to the Reaper API and see if you can get it, after, just need to write some other code to send this value to the Arduino via the Serial Port (that's easy to find examples).

Comment: I just took a look at the website you provided me. I have been looking through all the variables you can use with Reaper and it seems that for C++ there is: bool GetTempoTimeSigMarker(ReaProject* proj);

Comment: There also seems to be: bool GetTempoTimeSigMarker(double* bpmOut)
I'm not sure if the ReaProject* proj means that it takes the tempo of the whole project or if double* bpmOut does that.

Comment: Great, now you need to write a software to call this function and "print" to screen. Next is to plug in a Serial library so you can send it to the Arduino while Arduino keep waiting for messages.

Comment: I'm kind of a beginner to the Arduino world as I got my first one 3 days ago (which was a fake arduino nano). I didn't do my research on what you could do with it and because of the ATMEGA328 it couldn't control my keyboard. I also poured a drop of solder on the crystal which was destroyed. I now have the (also fake) arduino pro micro. Great little thing.
I don't know however, how to get my code to communicate with reaper.

Comment: @Hendriks3D, if you have a hot-air part remover, or if the crystals are thru-hole, you could move the crystal from the fake to the one that needs a crystal.  Note that when ATmega328 fuses are set to use a crystal, you can't use it without a crystal without changing the fuse settings.

Comment: well, the one that's broken has a broken crystal. I'm not sure if it works, but when I ordered the arduino micro, I also ordered another 16mhz crystal. Its a big one. The one that was originally on the nano is very small. I hope I can use the big one as a replacement. I could use my nano for other thins.